# Reasonable amount of data to be send via single send call

Tags: c, windows, send

I need to send files of different sizes to other clients via TCP sockets. Now I wonder how much data is reasonable for one send function call?

I won't send, for example, a whole 2 megabyte picture with 1 call to send - I'm going to chop that file into smaller buffers and send them one after another. But how small or big should these buffers be? I know that send doesn't guarantee to send all my data - I will check that.

Comment: max Ethernet MTU? 1500 Bytes

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter, as long as you're sending buffers larger than the MTU (typically a little under 1500 bytes or so).  If you send buffers larger than the MTU, the OS or NIC will fragment your packets into MTU-sized packets, you don't need to worry about doing the fragmentation yourself.  When that happens, the OS will block on the call to `send()` until all of the data has been sent or an error occurs—you could send all 2 MB in one call if you wanted, it won't be a problem.

You might get slightly worse performance with a really large call vs. a call just larger than the MTU, if only due to caching effects (i.e. you'll have more cache misses due to the data not all fitting in the L2 cache), but that's not likely to be very significant.

For file transfer, though, you'll actually get much better performance if you use the [`TransmitFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, rather than manually reading the data from the file into a buffer and then sending it.  That function is highly optimized for file transfers, because it can DMA the file data directly from the file system onto the NIC without needing to copy it from kernel space into user space and then back into kernel space.  This is called a [*zero-copy* operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy).

Comment: Stevens had a discussion on that topic in his book: Unix Network Programming. The idea was that sending enough to fill the OS buffers but not more is ideal, because it will reduce the numbers of system calls and transitions from user to kernel space.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know that kernel is going to chop my files and take care of it. Thank You very much for suggestion TransmitFile function but can it return number of already send bytes in mean-time? Because I need to make a progress bar. Or for example let's say that I want to send 50mega bytes file via single send call then I also won't be able to receive sent bytes in mean-time right? That is why I wanted to chop files by myself and send small buffers so I could easly program progress bar.

Or maybe there is a solution to it wirh TRansmitFile function?

Answer (score 0):

**Responsiveness of the thread that is doing the `send()` determines the size of data to be sent through a single `send()` call**

1. If your thread does not have anything else to do apart from the `send()`, you need not chop your data, you can send the whole data in one shot and let the OS do it's magic. In this case the send() call does not return till the entire data is sent and hence your thread cannot respond to / do anything else.
2. On the other hand, if you want the thread that is doing the send() to be responsive, you need to break down your data into smaller buffers. This way your thread gets execution time after the send() of each partial buffer. The size of your buffer should depend directly on the data speeds that you have and inversely with the expected responsiveness.

Comment: This is excatly what I thought. I wanted to chop files into buffer by myself and send it each after each so I could also make progress bar but I will wait for more infomations from Adam.